# Submit & monitor spark jobs via java in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

I have a java class which manage jobs and execute them via spark(using 1.6).
I am using the API  - sparkLauncher. startApplication(SparkAppHandle.Listener... listeners) in order to monitor the state of the job.
The problem is I moved to work in a real cluster environment and this way can’t work when the master and workers are not on the same machine, as the internal implementation is making a use of localhost only (loopback) to open a port for the workers to bind to.
The API sparkLauncher.launch() works but doesn’t let me monitor the status.
What is the best practice for cluster environment using a java code? 
I also saw the option of hidden Rest API, is it mature enough? Should I enable it in spark somehow (I am getting access denied, even though the port is open from outside) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REST API**

In addition to viewing the metrics in the UI, they are also available as JSON. This gives developers an easy way to create new visualizations and monitoring tools for Spark. The JSON is available for both running applications, and in the history server. The endpoints are mounted at /api/v1. Eg., for the history server, they would typically be accessible at http://:18080/api/v1, and for a running application, at http://localhost:4040/api/v1.

More details you can find [here.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/monitoring.html#rest-api)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to use the hidden rest API, but when executed from a different machine then the spark master, I am getting 403, the port is open in the machine, do you know of spark security configuration related to it?

Comment: Please check if you can access the port. 

you can try something as:

telnet server.hostname port

Comment: I cant from outside, but in the security group the port is open, should it be enabled somehow from spark configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Every SparkContext launches a web UI, by default on port 4040, that displays useful information about the application. This includes:

- A list of scheduler stages and tasks
- A summary of RDD sizes and memory usage
- Environmental information.
- Information about the running executors

You can access this interface by simply opening http://driver-node:4040 in a web browser. If multiple SparkContexts are running on the same host, they will bind to successive ports beginning with 4040 (4041, 4042, etc).

More details you can find [here.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)